# Is it good to have Memcache, APC and Varnish on LAMP servers

Tags: memcached, lamp, apc, varnish

I have 3 web servers I need to optimize. I currently have just a little over 2000 unique visitors a day and I want to improve performances on my servers to make sure when I will get more traffic everything will run smooth.

I read (on some blogs) APC, memcache and Varnish was the best tools to optimize web sites performances.

Is it good to use ALL three at the same time if I have static (for example terms and conditions page) and dynamic contents (user settings page)?

Thank you very much, J.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The number of visitors per day doesn't really mean anything, it is the peaks that kill you. If all 2000 hits per day come within a one minute peroid, then you might have problems, but if they are evenly spread out throughout the day even on a highly computational webapp you shouldn't have much issues.

Regardless, if you wish to scale, Varnish will probably help you the most as it allows you to set up client side caching which is as efficient as you can get as it limits the amount of interaction with your server.

APC and memcache are a fallback for when Varnish isn't able to serve a result. APC will speed up your PHP. memcache allows you to do things like grabbing some complex data from you database for a user and then serving up a cached version of that data for users for the next x minutes/days/weeks. This can make a huge difference if you have any time consuming queries.

**Edit**: I've been meaning to try out [Cloudflare CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for a while now and after doing so I had to come back and recommend it. They have a free account (which I'm using) and setting it up is pretty easy as long as you know how to change DNS records. Out of all the technologies mentioned, this will probably be the best first step you can take to speed up your site. Just so you know I don't have shares in Cloudflare or anything like that, but I'm seriously considering it. :)

Answer (score 8):

combination of all 3 is useful but use them for different things:
Varnish: can cache static content and deliver it extremely fast (reducing load on apache)
APC: stores php opcode so that calls which are processed by php are faster
Memcache: use as a temporary data store for your application to reduce calls to your db (db is typically a bottleneck)

if you have time on your hands, go for it with all 3 in the following order:
APC (fast to get up and running)
Varnish (needs a bit of configuration but is well worth it for static pages)
Memcache (code changes to make use of it, so obviously needs more thought and time)

Answer (score 1):

APC will help with any PHP pages and Memcached will help only if you use it explicitly.  I've never used Varnish so I don't know anything about it.

Edit: Varnish can cache both static and dynamically generated files to improve performance.

Comment: arf, i know its been a long time, but can you remove your edit? it helps serving cached php files as static content.

Comment: My statement isn't false, it will help serving static files.

Comment: can at least re-word it? Varnish helps serving both php files as static, as well as static files.

Answer (score 0):

All three can help a lot - but 2000 visitors a day really isn't that much.

Because APC is so easy to put into a LAMP system, I'd put it in there (and have for my own website, and that might get 5 visitors a day), but not bother about the others unless you had some kind of problem, that required the additional effor, such as far larger numbers of visitors, or hundreds of gigabytes of image/video downloads.

Memcache would also require some active use beyond basic configuration as well (or at least using a plugin that used it appropriately, for Wordpress or some other off-the-shelf software) - just installing the software does nothing at all.

Comment: I agree 2000 is not a lot, I just started 2 weeks ago. Yes I read about memcache and how to implement and I think I am good with that. What about Varnish?